# add an element before another with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following dom :

```
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">3</div>
<div class="test">4</div>
```

I would like to add before the nth test element a new element.

I am able to add a new element for all the test element with this code :

```
var newElement = "div class=\"test-new\""; 
$(".test").before(newElement);
```

But I am not able to select only the desired element thanks to an index(example : 3), these 2 codes throws an error :

```
var newElement = "div class=\"test-new\""; 
$(".test")(3).before(newElement);
$(".test")[3].before(newElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/):

```
$('<div />').addClass('test-new').insertBefore('.test');
```

To insert the element before **n-th** element use [eq](https://api.jquery.com/eq):

```
$('<div />').addClass('test-new').insertBefore($('.test').eq(0));
// Insert before first .test element

$('<div />').addClass('test-new').insertBefore($('.test').eq(3));
// Insert before third .test element
```

The `eq` index starts from **zero**.

> Reduce the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function to select an element by index and still keep it as a jQuery object. This function is [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$(".test").eq(3).before(newElement);
```

It is 0 based index, so `3` select the 4th element.

You should also wrap `var newElement = "div class=\"test-new\"";` between `<` and `>` to make a valid element:

```
var newElement = "<div class=\"test-new\">";
```

jQuery will interpret this as a new Node instead of a selector.

Answer (score 1):

Use this, should work like a charm :)

```
$(".test:nth-child(3)").before("<div>new item</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you cannot use the array syntax directly. You can do somethig like this:

```
$($(".test").get(3)).before(newElement);
```

Please note the double dollar  "$($(" this is necessary because the result of get() it's a DOM element not a jQuery element so you need to pass it to jQuery to use jQuery methods

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<div class="test">1</div>
<div class="test">2</div>
<div class="test">3</div>
<div class="test">4</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$( ".test:nth-child(2)" ).append( "<div>newtest</div>" );
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1
2
newtest
3
4
```

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/z1dvwrxo/)

Comment: `.append` will add the `div` to `.test`. I think he want to add it before `.test`.

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon,  then can use `prepend`, right??

Comment: No, prend is the same, it will be added to `.test` (only it will be first instead of last, that's the difference before append and prepend). You need `.after()` or `.before()`

Answer (score 0):

use the `eq` selector in jquery

```
var newElement = "div class=\"test-new\""; 
$(".test:eq(3)").before(newElement);
```

you should note, the `newElement` needs to be valid html, so you may want to change it to

```
var newElement = "<div class=\"test-new\"></div>"; 
$(".test:eq(3)").before(newElement);
```

fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/0qeh1rL1/